# twitter bootstrap affix without the animation

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a sticky top nav with a banner above it. It scrolls and sticks to the top correctly, however my user is asking for it to stick instantly, without the animation.

How can I disable the animation? I have tried:

```
.affix{
    transition-delay:0s;
}
```

that didn't work. Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
.affix{
    -moz-transition: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -o-transition: color 0 ease-in;
    transition: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but no, I tried that and it didn't make any difference.I just checked to make sure my styles are loaded after the boostrap.min.css, yes it is, but the animation still happens. Seems to animate only on sticking (when bootstrap css adds position:fixed) but not when unsticking.